# Weblogic Console not showing applications

Tags: oracle11g, weblogic

I use a Weblogic 10.3.6 Server on which I have numerous Enterprise Applications, Web Applications and Libraries deployed.
A few days ago, after a deployment glitch, the Console's deployment view does not show applications anymore. Only libraries are listed.

Does anyone know where I can start looking to fix the problem? How are enterprise and web applications found by the server to be displayed?

Edit 1:
Applications are in fact running, accessible and listed under the /Environment/Server//Deployments tab. From there I cannot update/start/stop them, however. They are missing only in the /Deployments view.

config/config.xml seems to be correct. All applications are listed there.

Comment: First, you can check that your applications are really installed in your domain by checking the config/config.xml file. All your applications and shraed libs will be present in this file.

Comment: Thanks for the input. config.xml shows all applications as it should. Also, I should have mentionend that in the console, I can see the applications as running under environment->server->myManagedServer->deployments tab. Just not in the main deployments view where I could also start/stop/update the applications.
I'll update the question accordingly.

Comment: Any errors in admin server's logs ?

Comment: Yes, although I'm not certain it is relevant: The application wls-cat.jar did not start. I'm currently trying to find out why. 
From what I understand of the Classloader Analysis Tool, I don't think it is the source of the problem, though possibly related.

<BEA-160001> <Error deploying Internal Application: weblogic.application.ModuleException: Context path '/wls-cat' is already in use by the module: wls-cat.war application: wls-cat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, that fixed it.

The Admin Server had an application called wls-cat.war installed, which failed upon server start. Apparently, it is Oracle's Classloader Analysis Tool which may come in useful in debugging. Not in this case, though. It failed on Admin Server startup. You cannot start, stop, deploy, undeploy or redeploy it with the standard means (it is an internal application).

In the end, I shut down the server and manually removed it from the /config/config.xml file.

```
<app-deployment>
    <name>wls-cat</name>
    <target>SBV00PG9_PERM01_ADMIN_SPU_PORTAL</target>
    <module-type>war</module-type>
    <source-path>${WL_HOME}/server/lib/wls-cat.war</source-path>
    <security-dd-model>DDOnly</security-dd-model>
    <cache-in-app-directory>false</cache-in-app-directory>
</app-deployment>
```

After that, the server shows applications again. I may need to reinstall the app at a later time, but for now the server seems to run well without it.

Very special thanks to [Emmanuel Collin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6316044/emmanuel-collin) for setting me on the right path.